# If-else: NSString

Tags: objective-c

I want to do the following thing: if country == "Россия", some actions..
But my if-else statement doesn't work. What do I should do? 
Thanks in advance. 
My code:

```
   NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
        NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
        NSString *country = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value: countryCode];
        NSLog(@"%@", country);

        if (country == @"Россия") {
            NSLog(@"GO RUSSIA");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"You are not russian");
        }
```

Comment: When you compare with `==` you're checking to see if the two pointers address the exact same object.  `isEqual` checks to see if the two objects, even if not the same object, have essentially equal contents.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder whether I'm the only one reading the documentation when I have a doubt...

Answer (score 8):

You need to use comparison methods from NSString:

```
if ([country isEqualToString: @"Россия"]) {
   ...
}
```

Simply using `==` will compare raw pointer values, not actual string values.

Comment: Thank you. Everything is true and works. :)

Comment: This rule acts with only NSString?

Comment: Not just with NSString, for example `NSNumber` has it's own `isEqualToNumber` method for doing comparison checks.

Comment: Normally you should compare any obj-c objects using special methods (isEqual: or isEqualToSmth: - custom classes can define custom comparison methods). Comparing pointers will almost never work

Comment: The only time you want to use `==` with objects is if you want to test if two variables point to the same instance.

Comment: `NSNumber` in particular can be confusing here, since some, but not all, `NSNumber`s are singletons. So you can have code where `num1 == num2` works fine when num1 and num2 are 12, but fails when they're 13. Always use the `isEqual` methods.

Comment: Also you can use `==` to compare `NSString const *`, but again it's better to use `isEqualToString` to prevent stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
if (country == @"Россия")
```

Is not the way to compare a NSString.

Try this:

```
if ([country isEqualToString:@"Россия"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the condition in ==  then only integer or Bool variable you can write 
And if you want to compare string contents then use equaltostring api below

```
if ([country isEqualToString: @"Россия"]) {
}
```

Comment: -1. comparing lengths is plain wrong in this case.

Comment: Because integer value you can compare in == .so above we are comparing length which is integer value

Comment: Because the OP wants to compare the content of the string. You "solution" would return `YES` even for the two strings `@"Russia"` and `@"FooBar"`

Comment: Ok got it gabriel thanks i forgot to think this scenario. Hence updated the answer

Comment: @gabriel updated the answer please have a look and let me know still i am going on wrongtrack

Comment: A part from the yoda-style of the sentence, what you are saying is sort of correct, even though non complete, not explicative and not an answer to the OP's problem.

Comment: Ok you managed to copy one of the answers above. At least is correct now.

Comment: @gabriel, lol i was not copying but only not able to express correctly:)