# How to compare two NSNumber numbers?

Tags: objective-c

So, in my previous question (check out this > [If-else: NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522276/if-else-nsstring)) I've known how to check two strings. But now my task is compare two numbers.

isEqualToNumber isn't I need. For example: if the first number has a value 13, the second value has a value 20. How to compare these numbers?

Thank you everyone. Which method do I should use?

My code:

```
    NSNumber *foo1 = @13;
    NSNumber *foo2 = @14;
```

I need to compare them:

```
if ( foo1 < foo2) {
    //some actions
}
```

Comment: How to change with special method? Is it possible?

Comment: @userboot, please give your comments

Answer (score 6):

```
 if ([foo1 compare:foo2] == NSOrderedAscending) { ... some actions ... }
```